# Memory not decreased after closing activities during profiling in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, memory-management, memory-leaks, profiling

I profiled my Android App using Android studio profiler to see memory usage after opening an Activity. Before opening the activity, the memory usage was around 200 MB, after opening the Activity and close it again, the memory usage was around 300 MB. I had expected the memory usage to decrease to the number before opening the Activity after it was destroyed.

I have tried forcing garbage collection and capturing the heap dump but I did not find memory leaks. What caused the memory to not be released after the Activities are destroyed? Does it indicate any underlying problems related to the memory usage?

[image: Memory usage]

Comment: Not familar with this memory profiler. Would this memory usage reflect cache usage? If so, it's possible the 200MB to 300MB jump is when the program is opened for the first time and then when you close it, the memory lingers as cache to help speed up opening it the next time. If there's a drop cache option like in Linux, try that and see if the memory goes back down.

Answer (score 0):

Here Firebase can get the most memory consuming interfaces, it can also display the time each interface and activity takes when the application is started, install it on the project and then open all the activities in your application to get information on which activities are using up the memory and how long it takes to load each screen.
When you open the activity, you will find the information in the `Run app` in `console` of `Android Studio`.